# react onChange doesn't seem to bubble properly

Tags: reactjs

When changing the input, it only prints `'input changes'` but not `'bubbles'`. Any idea why?

```
const InputWrapper = React.createClass({
    change () {
        console.log('input changes')
    },
    render () {
        return (
            <input onChange={this.change}/> 
        );
    }
});

const App = React.createClass({
    change () {
        console.log('bubbles');
    },
    render () {
        return (<InputWrapper onChange={this.change} />);
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/stevemao/6nxvvkwy/5/

**EDIT**: Doesn't it automatically bubble without calling `this.props.change` on `InputWrapper`? from the official docs: Like all DOM events, the onChange prop is supported on all native components and can be used to listen to bubbled change events.

Comment: When you say "only", do you mean that you want them both to appear? If you want to call the change method which prints bubbles, you have to use this.props.onChange instead of this.change

Comment: You are just setting `onChange` prop of `InputWrapper` but not calling it. https://jsfiddle.net/6nxvvkwy/6/

Comment: Doesn't it automatically bubble? In real dom I don't need to call it. from the official docs: Like all DOM events, the onChange prop is supported on all native components and can be used to listen to bubbled change events. @Qop

Answer (score 1):

Very simple... while you're calling `this.change` in `InputWrapper`, you're never making a call do the passed down `change` prop from `App`. You should modify it like so...

```
const InputWrapper = React.createClass({
  change () {
    console.log('input changes')
    this.props.onChange()
  },
  render () {
    return (
        <input onChange={this.change}/> 
    );
  }
```

});

Comment: Doesn't it automatically bubble? In real dom I don't need to call it. from the official docs: Like all DOM events, the onChange prop is supported on all native components and can be used to listen to bubbled change events.

Answer (score 1):

For anybody coming across this issue, the explanation I found is:

you should put the onChange on an HTML element (like span, div) for the bubbling to work. Because when you put it in **InputWrapper**, it is treated like a props, and since you never called this.props.onChange it doesn't work.

This code should work

```
const InputWrapper = React.createClass({
  change () {
    console.log('input changes')
  },
  render () {
    return (
        <input onChange={this.change}/> 
    );
  }
});

const App = React.createClass({
  change () {
    console.log('bubbles');
  },
  render () {
    return (
      <span onChange={this.change}>
       <InputWrapper  />
      </span>);
  }
});
```